# Django query, average count distinct

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-queryset

I have a `Donation` model defined as:

```
Donation
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    user = models.CharField()
```

Each user can donate multiple time to any project, so in db I can have the following:

```
 Donation
-------------------
 project | user
-------------------
 1       |  A
 2       |  A
 3       |  A
 1       |  B
 2       |  B
 2       |  C
```

Now, I need to compute the average of distinct project per user, in this case it would be:

```
A: 3
B: 2
C: 1
=> ( 3 + 2 + 1 ) / 3 = 2
```

What I have so far is the following:

```
distinct_pairs = Donation.objects.order_by('project')
         .values('user', 'project')
         .distinct()
```

This gives me a list of distincts `project`/`user` pairs, that I can work with in python.

I would like to know if there is a `query-only` way to do this?

My setup:

- Django 1.8
- PostgreSQL

Comment: Just wondering - why did you make the user a char field instead of a foreign key to a user model? Char field as user doesn't sound like the best practice, imo

Comment: It's because it's not a "real" user, it's mainly for simplifying the example.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to sum values for average, you can just count distinct values and divide by number of distinct users. Also `order_by` is redundant since we need only counts.

```
distinct_pairs_count = Donation.objects.values('user', 'project').distinct().count()

distinct_users_count = Donation.objects.values('user').distinct().count()

average = distinct_pairs_count / float(distinct_users_count)  # in Python 2
average = distinct_pairs_count / distinct_users_count         # in Python 3
```

EDIT: make it one QuerySet

I think you can achieve this by one query but I can't check it right now:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Avg

average = Donation.objects.values('user', 'project')
             .annotate(num_projects=Count('project', distinct=True))
             .aggregate(Avg('num_projects'))
```

See: [aggregating annotations in 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregating-annotations)

Comment: I'm not sure this will work. Consider the case where 5 users donate for the same project once. `distinct_pairs_count` will be 5 and `distinct_projects_count` will be 1, the average will be 5, and not 1...

Comment: @nobe4 yeah, sorry I meant divide by number of users, not projects. I've updated my answer.

Comment: This is a nice workaround, I'll use this until I can find a query only (if such exists), thanks.

Comment: @nobe4 I think this can be done with aggregation and annotation. Check my edit.

Comment: Seems promising, it gets the right integer (i.e. `1` where the division gets `1.13`).

Comment: Hmm, maybe it should be `user` instead of `project` in `(num_projects=Count('user', distinct=True))`, once again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121277/discussion-between-nobe4-and-akarilimano).